# Org2Blog and Two Factor Authentication

Tags: org-mode, init-file

new Emacs user here. I'm having trouble using org2blog to post to a client's WordPress site. The site has 2FA turned on, and won't let me post with it turned off. I got an application-specific password from WordPress for Emacs to use, and have tried to use the following code in my init.el file, entering that password manually:

```
(setq org2blog/wp-blog-alist
      '(("myblog"
         :url "https://XXXX.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php"
         :username "XXXX")))
```

With XXX replacing the data of course.

This gives me:

```
(error XML-RPC fault ‘Sorry, you are not allowed to edit pages.’)
```

I also tried using this code to make the authentication automatic:

```
(setq auth-sources '("~/.netrc"))
(setq credentials-my-blog (auth-source-user-and-password "my-blog"))
(setq org2blog/wp-blog-alist
      `(("my-blog"
         :url "https://XXXX.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php"
         :username ,(nth 0 (auth-source-user-and-password "my-blog"))
         :password ,(nth 1 (auth-source-user-and-password "my-blog")))))
```

and the .netrc file:

```
machine my-blog
login XXXX
password XXXX (this is the application-specific pw)
```

That just gives me an incorrect password error.

I'm flummoxed. I know that application-specific passwords can get me around 2FA because I've been using the Ulysses writing tool to access the same blog for a long time.

Can anyone help a bewildered Emacs n00b?

Comment: `.netrc` entries are normally on one line (but that may just be a formatting issue).